# Parse json and put into many tables

Tags: php, ajax, json, mootools

I was trying to print this json in some tables but i can't do it well, i hope you guys can help me, this is the json that i get by AJAX

```
<?php
    $json = array(
        'teams'=>array(
            array(
                'item'=>'tabla_clasif',
                'rows'=>array(
                    array('No'=>'1','logo1'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','pg'=>'3','pe'=>'0','pp'=>'0','gf'=>'9','gc'=>'2','dg'=>'7','pt'=>'12'),
                    array('No'=>'2','logo2'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','pg'=>'3','pe'=>'0','pp'=>'0','gf'=>'9','gc'=>'2','dg'=>'7','pt'=>'12'),
                    array('No'=>'3','logo3'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','pg'=>'3','pe'=>'0','pp'=>'0','gf'=>'9','gc'=>'2','dg'=>'7','pt'=>'12'),
                    array('No'=>'4','logo4'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','pg'=>'3','pe'=>'0','pp'=>'0','gf'=>'9','gc'=>'2','dg'=>'7','pt'=>'12'),
                    array('No'=>'5','logo5'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','pg'=>'3','pe'=>'0','pp'=>'0','gf'=>'9','gc'=>'2','dg'=>'7','pt'=>'12'),
                    array('No'=>'6','logo6'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','pg'=>'3','pe'=>'0','pp'=>'0','gf'=>'9','gc'=>'2','dg'=>'7','pt'=>'12'),
                    array('No'=>'7','logo7'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','pg'=>'3','pe'=>'0','pp'=>'0','gf'=>'9','gc'=>'2','dg'=>'7','pt'=>'12'),
                    array('No'=>'8','logo8'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','pg'=>'3','pe'=>'0','pp'=>'0','gf'=>'9','gc'=>'2','dg'=>'7','pt'=>'12'),
                    array('No'=>'9','logo9'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','pg'=>'3','pe'=>'0','pp'=>'0','gf'=>'9','gc'=>'2','dg'=>'7','pt'=>'12'),
                    array('No'=>'10','logo10'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','pg'=>'3','pe'=>'0','pp'=>'0','gf'=>'9','gc'=>'2','dg'=>'7','pt'=>'12'),
                    array('No'=>'11','logo11'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','pg'=>'3','pe'=>'0','pp'=>'0','gf'=>'9','gc'=>'2','dg'=>'7','pt'=>'12'),
                    array('No'=>'12','logo12'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','pg'=>'3','pe'=>'0','pp'=>'0','gf'=>'9','gc'=>'2','dg'=>'7','pt'=>'12'),
                    array('No'=>'13','logo13'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','pg'=>'3','pe'=>'0','pp'=>'0','gf'=>'9','gc'=>'2','dg'=>'7','pt'=>'12'),
                    array('No'=>'14','logo14'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','pg'=>'3','pe'=>'0','pp'=>'0','gf'=>'9','gc'=>'2','dg'=>'7','pt'=>'12'),
                    array('No'=>'15','logo15'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','pg'=>'3','pe'=>'0','pp'=>'0','gf'=>'9','gc'=>'2','dg'=>'7','pt'=>'12'),
                    array('No'=>'16','logo16'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','pg'=>'3','pe'=>'0','pp'=>'0','gf'=>'9','gc'=>'2','dg'=>'7','pt'=>'12')
                )
            ),
            array(
                'item'=>'goles_marca',
                'rows'=>array(
                    array('No'=>'1','logo1'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gf'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'2','logo2'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gf'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'3','logo3'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gf'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'4','logo4'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gf'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'5','logo5'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gf'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'6','logo6'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gf'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'7','logo7'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gf'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'8','logo8'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gf'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'9','logo9'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gf'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'10','logo10'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gf'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'11','logo11'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gf'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'12','logo12'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gf'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'13','logo13'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gf'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'14','logo14'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gf'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'15','logo15'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gf'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'16','logo16'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gf'=>'3')

                )
            ),  
            array(
                'item'=>'goles_recib',
                'rows'=>array(
                    array('No'=>'1','logo1'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gc'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'2','logo2'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gc'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'3','logo3'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gc'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'4','logo4'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gc'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'5','logo5'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gc'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'6','logo6'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gc'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'7','logo7'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gc'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'8','logo8'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gc'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'9','logo9'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gc'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'10','logo10'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gc'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'11','logo11'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gc'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'12','logo12'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gc'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'13','logo13'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gc'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'14','logo14'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gc'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'15','logo15'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gc'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'16','logo16'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','gc'=>'3')
                )
            ),  
            array(
                'item'=>'efect_gol',
                'rows'=>array(
                    array('No'=>'1','logo1'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','eg'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'2','logo2'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','eg'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'3','logo3'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','eg'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'4','logo4'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','eg'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'5','logo5'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','eg'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'6','logo6'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','eg'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'7','logo7'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','eg'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'8','logo8'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','eg'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'9','logo9'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','eg'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'10','logo10'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','eg'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'11','logo11'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','eg'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'12','logo12'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','eg'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'13','logo13'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','eg'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'14','logo14'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','eg'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'15','logo15'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','eg'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'16','logo16'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','eg'=>'3')
                )
            ),  
            array(
                'item'=>'remate_total',
                'rows'=>array(
                    array('No'=>'1','logo1'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','rt'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'2','logo2'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','rt'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'3','logo3'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','rt'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'4','logo4'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','rt'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'5','logo5'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','rt'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'6','logo6'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','rt'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'7','logo7'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','rt'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'8','logo8'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','rt'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'9','logo9'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','rt'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'10','logo10'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','rt'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'11','logo11'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','rt'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'12','logo12'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','rt'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'13','logo13'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','rt'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'14','logo14'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','rt'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'15','logo15'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','rt'=>'3'),
                    array('No'=>'16','logo16'=>'images/lobos.png','team1'=>'atlante','pj'=>'3','rt'=>'3')
                )               
            ),
        )
    );
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

I need to put them into tables, each table for each item, i have tried with some each until i get every  or row but it was really hard

What is the best way to make it?

```
        onSuccess : function(data) {}
```

A example of the HTML I am looking for would be:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>Logo</td>
            <td>Team</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><img src="images/lobos.png" /></td>
            <td>atlante</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That's a nice array you have there. So what have you tried?

Comment: Can you explain how do you want to populate the table? Post a first row example to be more clear. Then I can help you with it.

Comment: Hello, i need to make a table for each 'item' of array.

For example: 

`<table>
<thead>
   <tr>
       <td>No</td>
       <td>Logo</td>
       <td>Team</td>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><img src="images/lobos.png" />
      <td>atlante</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>`

Comment: I made it, that is my solution:
   `onSuccess : function(data) {
      data.teams.each(function(item){
        tbody += "<table class='hidden myWidget'><tbody>"
        tbody += "<tr>"
        item.rows.each(function(Row){
          for(var key in Row) {
              var value = Row[key];
               tbody += "<td>"+value+"</td>"
          }
          tbody += "</tr>"
        });
       tbody += "</tbody></table>"
     });
   document.getElementById('Newtable').innerHTML = tbody;`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another suggestion, using the Element constructor. You should also take a look at [**MooTools More and the HTML table**](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Interface/HtmlTable), probably a good alternative here if you can re-format the JSON a bit.

Anyway, I would do what you are looking for this way:

```
json = JSON.parse(json);

json.teams.each(function (team) {

    var newTable = new Element('table', {
        class: 'hidden myWidget'
    }).inject(document.body);
    var thead = new Element('thead').inject(newTable);

    var tittleRow = new Element('tr');
    for (var title in team.rows[0]) new Element('td', {
        'html': title
    }).inject(tittleRow);
    tittleRow.inject(thead);

    var tbody = new Element('tbody').inject(newTable);
    team.rows.each(function (row) {
        var newRow = new Element('tr');
        for (var value in row) new Element('td', {
            'html': row[value]
        }).inject(newRow);
        newRow.inject(tbody);
    });
});
```

#### Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2KjSn/

Ps. You should post your answers when you find a solution yourself and not edit the question. This way it might be useful for others also.